# How can this Java algorithm be faster

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, linked-list, ascii

I have this loop which splits a Boolean LinkedList by 8 bits and return the ASCII value of each byte in a buffer. The function return the string buffer.

This code is extremely slow if the LinkedList's size is big. I try to change the `Iterator` with a simple looping, but it's still slow.

How can this algorithm be really fast ? Maybe with multi-threading ?

**Note:** The size of the linkedList is not always divisible by 8.

```
public String toString(){

        String buffer = "";
        String output = "";

        LinkedList<Boolean> bits = this.bits;

        for(Iterator it = this.bits.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
            if(buffer.length() >= 8){
                output += (char)Integer.parseInt(buffer, 2);
                buffer = "";
            }

            buffer += ((Boolean)it.next() == false) ? "0" : "1";
        }

        if(buffer != "")
            output += (char)Integer.parseInt(buffer, 2);

        return output;
}
```

Comment: The last non-8bits buffer will be converted in its ascii value and the value is concatenate to the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use `StringBuilder` initialized with expected capacity for output:

   ```
   StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(bits.size() / 8 + 1);
   ```
2. Use bitwise operations instead of `parseInt()`, something like this:

   ```
   int i = 0;          
   int c = 0;
   for(Boolean b: bits){
       if (i > 0 && i % 8 == 0){
           out.append((char) c);
           c = 0;
       }
       c = (c << 1) | (b ? 1 : 0);
       i++;
   }
   out.append((char) c); // Not sure about the desired behaviour here
   ```

Comment: Wow, the demo file I compressed with my code took more than 1 minute and yours take less than 1 second. I just don't understand why you do i%8 !=1. the modulo could be 2, 3, 4.. ? the code inside must append the non-8 bits char value in the string builder.

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard: Yes, this code contains an off-by-one error, wait a minute.

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard: Seems to be fine now.

Comment: I make a couple of tests, but It seems to be okay.

Comment: I humbly believe my code below is even more efficient as it does not use StringBuilder.

Comment: Your algo does not return the expected value

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard: 107 is `k`, this code produces `ak`, so that it works correctly.

Comment: At line System.out.print(c), that produce 48, 181.. not 97 107

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard: Note the `int i = 0`.

Comment: @axtavt I am trying to find the solution, but I never use bit shift, so am not really sure of what I am doing..

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard: It works correctly. Check result after the last `append`.

Comment: Ahh, you're right, I just see I was watching the result before the end. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

These suggestions will *give you enough performance still keeping the code simple and readable*. First test using these changes and if doesn't meet your performance requirements then slowly introduce optimization techniques suggested in other answers

1. Use `BitSet` instead of `LinkedList<Boolean>`
2. use `StringBuilder output;` instead of `String output;`
3. use `StringBuilder buffer;` instead of `String buffer;`
4. Use `Integer.valueOf()` instead of `Integer.parseInt`. `valueOf` uses cache for values below 128 i think.

Comment: @beny23 the OP is creating integer out of string for which he can use valueOf

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation is slow especially for large lists (since strings are immutable they have to be copied around which takes some time and each copy requires more space as well). Use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String` to append to. In other words: `buffer` and `output` should be `StringBuilder` instances.

Answer (score 2):

As others suggested - use BitSet. For the rest, I think the method below is pretty efficient:

```
    public String toString() {
        char[] bytes = new char[bits.size() / 8 + ((bits.size() % 8 > 0) ? 1 : 0)];
        int bitCounter = 0;
        int word = 0;
        int byteCounter = 0;
        for (boolean b : bits) {
            word = (word << 1) | (b ? 1 : 0);
            if (bitCounter == 7) {
                bytes[byteCounter] = (char) word;
                ++byteCounter;
                bitCounter = 0;
                word = 0;
            } else {
                ++bitCounter;
            } // else
        } // foreach
        bytes[byteCounter] = (char) word;
        return new String(bytes);
    } // toString() method
```

Here is possibly a better alternative that does not use byte counter:

```
        public String toString() {
            int size = bits.size() / 8 + ((bits.size() % 8 > 0) ? 1 : 0);
            if (size == 0) {
                return "";
            } // if
            char[] bytes = new char[size];
            int bitCounter = 0;
            int word = 0;
            for (boolean b : bits) {
                if (bitCounter % 8 == 0
                        && bitCounter > 0) {
                    bytes[(bitCounter - 1) / 8] = (char) word;
                    word = 0;
                } // if
                word = (word << 1) | (b ? 1 : 0);
                ++bitCounter;
            } // foreach
            bytes[size - 1] = (char) word;
            return new String(bytes);
        } // toString() method
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep buffer as an `int`. I mean

```
 buffer = buffer << 1 + (((Boolean)it.next() == false) ? 0 : 1);
```

instead of

```
 buffer += ((Boolean)it.next() == false) ? "0" : "1";
```

Also use `StringBuilder` for output. This is a small change here but always a bit.

Comment: I humbly suggest you use `buffer * 2` in the first code sample or `buffer = (buffer << 1) | ((Boolean)it.next() ? 1 : 0);`. Within one expression, better don't mix arithmetic and bit manipulation, even if they do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
 int ch = 0;
 int n = 0;

 for (Boolean bit : bits) {
   ch <<= 1;
   if (bit) {
     ch++;
   }
   if (++n == 8) {
     b.append((char)ch);
     n = 0;
     ch = 0;
   }
 }

 if (n > 0) {
   b.append((char)ch);
 }  

 System.out.println(b.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuffer or stringBuilder instead of String for your buffer and output vars.

String vars are immutable, so every operations creates a new instance in heap, while StringBuilder and StringBuffer are not.